# How to set the back color of the header in a radGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik-grid, radgridview

I want to change the back color of the header in radGridView.Is there any way to change except using themes for that?(winform)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make some effort before you ask here. You can read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void radGridView1_ViewCellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellElement is GridHeaderCellElement)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.Text == "Your header cell text") //checking for the text in header cell
        {
            e.CellElement.DrawBorder = true;
            e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
            e.CellElement.GradientStyle = Telerik.WinControls.GradientStyles.Solid;
            e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.Green;
            e.CellElement.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```